# How to sorting array with case insensitive?

Tags: php

Input array:

```
 Array
    (
        [6] => Array
            (
                [name] => Ashsish
            )

        [11] => Array
            (
                [name] => Nishu
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [name] => Pooja
            )

        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => ankur
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [name] => boby
            )

        [9] => Array
            (
                [name] => chintu
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [name] => darshan
            )

        [8] => Array
            (
                [name] => honey
            )

        [10] => Array
            (
                [name] => jay
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [name] => pravin
            )

        [7] => Array
            (
                [name] => sagar
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [name] => zalak
            )

    )
```

Comment: Have you tried [`uasort()`](http://php.net/uasort)?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`uasort()`](http://php.net/uasort) with [`strcasecmp()`](http://php.net/strcasecmp) for the comparison:

```
uasort($list, function($a, $b) {
    return strcasecmp($a['name'], $b['name']);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`sort`](http://php.net/sort):

```
sort($input_array, SORT_NATURAL | SORT_FLAG_CASE)
```

Note that this requires **PHP 5.4.0+** for `SORT_NATURAL` AND `SORT_FLAG_CASE` use.  See [`sort` manual](http://php.net/sort) for details.

Comment: This doesn't sort the array properly.

Comment: @Jack, please define "properly".  This does require `PHP 5.4` for `SORT_NATURAL` AND `SORT_FLAG_CASE` as sort_flags parameter.  Updating answer.

Comment: For one, each element in the array is not a string, but an array. I suppose you didn't test it?

Answer (score 0):

**natcasesort**

(PHP 4, PHP 5)

natcasesort — Sort an array using a case insensitive "natural order" algorithm
Description

```
 bool natcasesort ( array &$array )
```

for more
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.natcasesort.php